# Broadcast not received by my class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm using the following to broadcast an intent from my MainActivity's onCreate:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Here is my receiver class:

```
public class MyNewReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("OK", "RECEIVED");
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any errors but I'm not getting my `Log` either.

I know this isn't really what `BroadcastReceiver`s are for, but in this case I need to trigger it manually once.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit intents (an Intent where you specify the target class) are not meant to fire BroadcastReceivers, they instead receive intents via implcit intents using IntentFilters. The reason of this is that the purpose of the whole broadcast mechanism is to be able to send events without knowing who is going to listen for them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving

The way to achieve this is:

First declare your BroadcastReceiver in your manifest along with the actions it is suppossed to listen.
Here you have an example on how to do it:

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.MyNewReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.action.string" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The action string could be any string you like, but it's usually a good idea to pick something in a java package style with the package of your own app.

Finally send the intent specifying the action string this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your.action.string");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope it helps.